# Rank constrained SDP

Tags: computational-geometry, constrained-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I would like to optimize a function of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i,j=1}^N c_{i,j} \mathbf{x}_i \cdot \mathbf{x}_j,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbf{R}^d$. Is it possible to state this as SDP?

I guess that an SDP variable would be somehow related to the Gramian $G$ of the vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}$, with the constraint $rank(G) \leq d$. Is it possible to impose such a constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraint $\mbox{rank}(X) <= d$ is in general a non-convex constraint.  Sorry.

A commonly used approach is to minimize the Schatten 1-norm of X (the sum of singular values of X) as a surrogate for minimizing the rank.  This works similarly to minimizing the 1-norm of a vector x as a way of minimizing the number of nonzero entries in x.